# Get data automaticly when inputs are filled

Tags: php

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      // Here the code captures the inputs that entered. 
        Based on the inputs the script shows the associated information.
}

    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="postc">
    <input type="text" name="nr">
    <button name="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

How to check that both of the inputs are filled and if they are filled automaticly load the PHP code to get the data.  **(I'm a beginner)**

I hope I explained it right!

**Example page**

http://bit.ly/1hx0EKS

Comment: _submit the form automatically_? That doesn't look very user-friendly.

Comment: i did'nt understood. what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: You might need to use `jQuery`.

Comment: U can use Javascript form.submit

Comment: Pl don't try this. Go through PHP manual ....

Comment: how will you know that form is filled enough to get posted to server? Isn't that unusual thing you are asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like below:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" name="myForm" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" name="postc" onchange="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="nr" onchange="submitForm()">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

this function is called anytime you fill an input of your form. It provides to get your input values and submit dynamically the form ONLY when you filled all your (in this case) inputs.

```
function submitForm() {
    var postc = document.forms["myForm"]["postc"].value;
    var nr = document.forms["myForm"]["nr"].value;

    if (postc != "" && nr != "")
        document.myForm.submit();
}
```

**EDIT**

This is a full *working* example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Your title</title>

        <script>
            function submitForm() {
                var postc = document.forms["myForm"]["postc"].value;
                var nr = document.forms["myForm"]["nr"].value;

                if (postc != "" && nr != "") {
                    document.myForm.submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" name="myForm" action="#">
            <input type="text" name="postc" onchange="submitForm()">
            <input type="text" name="nr" onchange="submitForm()">
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['postc'])){
                echo "postc value: " . $_POST['postc'] . '<br />';
                echo "nr value: " . $_POST['nr'];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: it doenst show info if i fill the inputs how to make it submit ?

Comment: i missed the `action="page.php"` attribute for the form. Consider to change `page.php` with the page in which then you check your request